# Bootstrap page redirect after modal pop up button close

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I want to redirect a particular page if modal pop up closed. My code will mention below :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="logint-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" data-backdrop="static">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" align="center">
            <img class="" id="img_logo" src="logo.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="div-forms" style="margin:20px 0 20px;">
            <p class="text-center">
                <!--<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/19/19973.png" class="img-responsive center-block" height="50px" width="50px">-->
            </p>
            <p class="text-center">
                <?php echo Email/Mobile already exist;?>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default modal_close" data-dismiss="modal">Okay</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".modal_close").bind("click", function() { 
            window.location.href = "login.php";
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please resolve my issue the above code doesnot work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `hide.bs.modal` to achieve your goal:

```
$('.modal_close').on('hide.bs.modal', function (event) {
  window.location.href = "login.php";
})
```

From the documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/#events

Answer (score 1):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      window.location.href = "login.php"
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" id="mymodal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```